# Slick carousel triggering click event when swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, slick.js

I am using Slick carousel with lightcase.js and the problem I am facing is that when I am swiping slick the click event is triggered and the pop up is showed immediately. Sometimes the click event is not fired but this just happen when you swiped all the slide, if you just swipe half the way the event is triggered. If someone else have faced that problem I appreciate if you could tell me of a possible workaround.

This is my html sctructure:

```
<div class="slider multiple-items">
    <a href="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/1b.jpg" id="example1" class="showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
  <img src="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/1b.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/2b.jpg" id="example2" class="showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
  <img src="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/2b.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/3b.jpg" id="example3" class="showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
  <img src="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/2b.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/4b.jpg" id="example4" class="showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
  <img src="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/4b.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/5b.jpg" id="example5" class="showcase" data-rel="lightcase">
  <img src="http://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/project/img/examples/5b.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

And the js I am using:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});

$('a[data-rel^=lightcase]').lightcase();
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonsrating the current behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/zLk1otb3/

Comment: @Jhonnathan Couldnt see any pop up on screen on fiddle.

Comment: @dk_dragonknight when you click on an image or finish a drag action the modal box is getting opened

Regards

Comment: Since you are combining lightcase and slick with images wrapped inside links whenever user clicks on images hyperlink source gets loaded and shown with lightcase as pop up. You can simply use lightcase only to show images on UI and have carousel slideshow after user clicks on images.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-rel="lightcase:slideshow"` to link items if you want to see slideshow carousel on click event. Pop up you see is pop up for link element from lightcase view.